# Migrating from DataStax Enterprise to Scylla on-prem

Tags: datastax-enterprise, scylla

I was reading up Scylla's documentation because we're planning on migrating from DSE to Scylla on-prem. However, [in their documentation](https://docs.scylladb.com/operating-scylla/procedures/cassandra_to_scylla_migration_process/), they say that the DSE SSTable format is not supported.

[Here](https://www.scylladb.com/2019/06/04/migrating-to-scylla-cloud/) they reference that migrating from DSE is supported, but this process relates to migrating to Scylla Cloud, which is not the case. The final target would be Scylla on-prem.

How can we migrate from DSE to Scylla? Is this not possible without a custom-built application?

Answer (score 6):

I'll try to answer in a few points:

1. It is true that the DSE sstable format is different and proprietary. This doesn't mean migration isn't possible, you will simply have to adopt a migration strategy that doesn't involve dropping existing sstable files into Scylla. There are a few of those available.
2. Migration from DSE is what the folks at ScyllaDB do all day, to the Scylla Cloud, to your own Cloud infrastructure, to your on-prem servers, with downtime, without downtime - doesn't really matter, anything is possible.
3. Migrations are basically about moving your data. There are several approaches, and picking the best one for you would really depend on your specific use case. I delivered a webinar on migration strategies a while ago, an the strategies have been expanded upon and enhanced since, but it will still give you a good idea: https://www.scylladb.com/2019/04/02/spark-file-transfer-and-more-strategies-for-migrating-data-to-and-from-a-cassandra-or-scylla-cluster/